# Python datetime.date issue TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, datetime

I am have a problem that I need help with, I have the following python script and trying figure pass values to datetime.date.

`EXPIRE_DATE = ("{}, {}, {}" .format(YEAR,MONTH_NUMBER,DAY)).strip()`

This returns `2023, 6, 14`

Now, I want to pass `"EXPIRE_DATE"` to `datetime.date`. But, I am getting an error:

```py
today = datetime.date.today()
someday = datetime.date(EXPIRE_DATE)

Error:
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: note: `2023, 6, 14` (result of `"{}, {}, {}" .format`) is a string

Comment: What's the reason for turning your year, month, and date values into a string before trying to create the date? There are ways to build a date from a string (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime and then use `.date()` to take just the date portion, or third party libraries like the excellent `dateutil`) but since you appear to have integers to start with they shouldn't be necessary. Or are `YEAR` etc themselves strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code creates a string while [datetime.date()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) requires three integers as parameters (year, month, day).

```
EXPIRE_DATE = ("{}, {}, {}" .format(YEAR,MONTH_NUMBER,DAY)).strip()
```

Instead you can just pass the year, month and day to the function directly, like such;

```
YEAR = 2000
MONTH_NUMBER = 10
DAY = 30

today = datetime.date.today()
someday = datetime.date(YEAR, MONTH_NUMBER, DAY)

print(someday) // Prints '2000-10-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `EXPIRE_DATE` is a `String` and as the error correctly says you need three `Integers` as arguments for `datetime.date`. Specifically, something like:

```py
YEAR = 2021
MONTH = 3
DAY = 17

today = datetime.date.today()
someday = datetime.date(YEAR, MONTH, DAY)
```

Further reading on `datetime.date`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date